# Any ideas how to recover my 400 UNI drop from an old instadapp mcd vault smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, tokens, erc-20, etherscan

I apologize for having to post this again because my lack of reputation but maybe I can reword it better this time.

My ETH address:
0x34A2860bbbA761ae27005799b02D3DbD8b4b5fEb

Old InstadApp MCD Vault Smart Contract:
0xc653461d3D4c6AD53c16ebE16fa07f820e115139

as you can see on etherscan the MCD Volt smart contract has 400 UNI ERC tokens within the wallet https://etherscan.io/address/0xc653461d3D4c6AD53c16ebE16fa07f820e115139

Linked for convenience. I've tried connecting the owner wallet of the smart contract with web3 connection through etherscan but I can't figure out what I could possibly try to write and execute in the smart contract to get that UNI to a different address, any address at all. Perhaps there's a way I can find the private key some how?

It's completely useless just sitting in there, I would happily pay someone a bounty if they could help me figure out how to get it into my possession. Because how I see it is I don't own it currently anyway so I have nothing to lose only gain and I would love to share the wealth if we could accomplish this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, go to https://old.instadapp.io/exit they Key to the whole thing being the /exit page.

Answer (score 0):

Before following the procedure, open in you wallet the address where you know that you have to be claimed UNI tokens

1. Go to UNISWAP app :  https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap
2. Click on 3 dots menu to the top left side of the page.
3. Then in the menu click on Claim UNI option.
4. Enter your Instadapp wallet address in the recipient input box and click on Claim UNI button
5. Confirm your transaction. And you will receive your UNI token on your Instadapp contract wallet.
6. Later you can withdraw UNI tokens from the Instadapp dashboard (old & new) or via small code snippet.

Reference: https://discuss.instadapp.io/t/how-to-claim-uni-token-on-instadapp/168